# Align dynamically in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to align my controls using Xamarin Android.

I made a foreach loop with a GridView:

```
var layout = new GridLayout(this);        
        SetContentView(layout); 

        foreach(JObject s in theArray)
        {
            string Text = s.GetValue("Name").ToString();

            var sbLabel = new TextView(this);
            sbLabel.Text = Text;

            var sbButton = new Button(this);
            sbButton.Text = "Info";

            layout.AddView(sbLabel);
            layout.AddView(sbButton);

        }
```

But I want the TextView and Button to be underneath each other.

How it looks now:
[image]

How I want it to look:
[image]

Can someone help me with aligning this properly? If possible also centered in the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by wrapping you `Label` and `Button` in `LinearLayout`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    var relative = new LinearLayout(this);
    relative.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

    var sbLabel = new TextView(this);
    sbLabel.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;

    var sbButton = new Button(this);

    sbLabel.Text = i.ToString(); ;

    sbButton.Text = "Info";

    relative.AddView(sbLabel);
    relative.AddView(sbButton);
    layout.AddView(relative);
}
```

---

**In alternative** you can do this with a `RelativeLayout` (More performant) too (it's a bit more code and you must have and `Id` for the `Label`):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    var relative = new RelativeLayout(this);
    var params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

    var sbLabel = new TextView(this);
    var layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    layoutparams.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
    sbLabel.LayoutParameters = layoutparams;
    var sbButton = new Button(this);

    sbLabel.Id = i;
    sbLabel.Text = i.ToString();

    sbButton.Text = "Info";

    params1.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, sbLabel.Id);
    relative.AddView(sbLabel);
    relative.AddView(sbButton, params1);

    layout.AddView(relative);
}
```

---

**Final result** (Same for both options above):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to center the labels above?

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it.